# Question about vectors in the Grassmannian in this example

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, grassmannian

Consider $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ defined by $(t,s) \mapsto (t^2 + 2s, t^3 + 3ts, t^4 + 4t^2 s)$.

Let $Gr$ denote the Grassmannian and let $Gr(2, T\mathbb R^3) = \bigcup_{x \in T\mathbb R^3} Gr(2, T_x \mathbb R^3)$.

Note that

$$ {\partial f \over \partial t} = {\partial f \over \partial s} + s(0, 3, 8t)$$

Now let $v_1 = {\partial f \over \partial s} = (2,3t, 4t^2)$ and $v_2 = (0,3,8t)$.

I want to give a vector that is in $Gr(2,T\mathbb R^3)$. I have the solution but I don't understand why it's true:

We column-row eliminate the vectors $v_1, v_2$ so that we have

$$ v_1' = (1, 0, -2t^2) \text{ and } v_2' = (0,1, {8\over 3}t)$$

Then the vector I am looking for is given by

$$ (f, -2t^2, {8\over 3}t)$$

> Please could someone explain to me why this holds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you (they?) giving local coordinates on $G(2,\Bbb R^3)$? In a large open set of the Grassmannian, namely, the set of $2$-planes that project isomorphically onto the $e_1e_2$-plane, we take a basis for the plane to be $\{(1,0,a),(0,1,b)\}$, and $(a,b)$ gives a chart on that subset.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really had no idea. Do you know of any book or lecture notes where this is discussed? (I think it would help me to see more than just one example... and perhaps some related concepts...)

Comment: What is your level and background?

Comment: I just learned about Grassmannians last week. I have knowledge of all the basic stuff like linear algebra, analysis and topology but I don't really know any differential geometry yet.

Comment: The standard references I know on Grassmannians are graduate-level texts on manifolds, differential geometry, and algebraic geometry. There's nothing much more involved than what I sketched for you, but the books don't do concrete examples and are a bit sophisticated. Offhand, I might suggest you glance at Joe Harris's *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course*. Most of these books will tie things into exterior algebra and wedge products, which I suspect you've not seen.

Comment: Thank you, you're right I have not seen exterior algebra and wedge product.