# The last coordinates of basis vectors are a chart

Tags: differential-geometry, grassmannian

Let $Gr$ denote the Grassmannian and let $Gr(2, T\mathbb R^3) = \bigcup_{x \in T\mathbb R^3} Gr(2, T_x \mathbb R^3)$.

Consider one $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, that is, one element of $Gr(2, T_x \mathbb R^3)$ for some $x$.

Then if $\{(1,0,a),(0,1,b)\}$ is a basis of this $2$-subspace, $(a,b)$ is a chart on this subspace. (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1321317/180995))

But I don't understand why this should be true.

> Please could someone explain to me, in as simple as possible words,
>   why the last coordinates of two basis vectors give a chart for the
>   subspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the $xy$-plane $L_0$ as an element in $Gr(2, 3)$ (the set of all two planes in $\mathbb R^3$). Let $U$ be the subset in $Gr(2, 3)$, such that $L \in U$ if and only if $L$ does not contain the $z$-axis. Note that this is the same as saying that (check)

$L \in U$ if and only if $\pi_L:= \pi|_L : L \to L_0$ is an isomorphism, where $\pi : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2 \cong L_0$ is the projection to the $xy$-plane.

Now note that $\pi_L^{-1}$ as a linear map is completely determined by its action on $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$. Let $(a, b)$ be given by

$$\pi_L^{-1} (1,0,0) = (1, 0, a),\ \ \pi_L^{-1} (0,1,0) = (0, 1, b)$$

and define $\phi : U \to \mathbb R^2$ be given by $\phi(L) = (a, b)$. Then $\phi$ is a bijection and so define a chart on $Gr(2, 3)$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, or at least I think I do: We could take any two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ say, $v$ and $w$ and then take the last coordinates of $\pi_L^{-1}v, \pi_L^{-1}w$ and these would define a chart on $U$?

Comment: Note that $\pi_L^{-1}$ has domain $\mathbb R^2$. So we pick two fixed linerarly independent vectors (in the answer I pick those two as $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0,1,0)$). @astudent

Comment: But we could have chosen $(1,2,0)$ and $(1,3,0)$ instead just as well, right?

Comment: Yes. Any two linearly independent one would do. But it is custom to use that two.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And how did you know that $\pi_L^{-1} (1,0,0)$ is of the form $(1,0,a)$ and not $(a,b,c)$?

Comment: Got it: Because $\pi$ is a projection the inverse only applies to the third component.

Comment: Is the set $Gr(2,3)$ a set of paris $(u,v)$ where $u$ is a vector in a plane and $v$ is the normal vector of the plane?

Comment: No. $Gr(2, 3)$ is the set of all planes in $\mathbb R^3$. @astudent

Comment: Yes, I know but when we write elements down explicitly it seems to me that a normal vector would describe a plane. I mean we have to write it down somehow, right?

Comment: In my answer I did not use normal vector. Indeed, both $(1,0,a)$ and $(0,1,b)$ are vectors in that plane $L$. @astudent

Comment: When you write "that do not contain the $z$ axis" you really mean "whose normal is not parallel to the $x$-axis" right? Because it seems to me that your $U$ also contains the plane parallel to the $yz$-plane and going through $(1,0,0)$ -- yet this plane does not contain the $z$-axis.

Comment: @astudent : In my answer, all planes must pass through the origin. (And this is the usual definition of the Grassmanians)